# Server vsFTPd connection failed

Tags: unix, ftp, debian, passwd, vsftpd

I am trying to connect on ftp localhost but the login/password always fail.
I have installed vsFTPd.
I guess i have to modify passwd.conf. But how must I process?
I have this line :

```
paul:x:1000:1000:paul,,,:/home/paul:/bin/false
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can set new password with `passwd` (enter).
or login with root privileges and type (sudo) `passwd [username]`, and change password then.

And maybe need change config ftp server and set `local_enable=YES` and `chroot_local_user=YES` in the `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` file config, for allow users in `/etc/passwd` to login.

Answer (score 0):

You should add system user in chroot file like.

```
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

after need to restart vsftpd service.

Visit [here](https://www.solutionclub.in/how-to-install-and-setup-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts.html) for more detail.